# For some reason on xCode it shows a thin white bar on the side of my simulator.

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When ever I try running the simulator, this thin white bar on the side of the simulator appears. There has been times that i've managed to remove it but Im not sure how I did it.

[Click here to see example of the issue i'm having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1INI.png)

Kind Regards,
Chris

Comment: Did you try quitting xcode/simulator and restarting the computer?

Comment: Are you using a variable size device simulator? Have you double-checked the constraints of your initial view controller?

Comment: @thelaws I've tried this dozen's of times and still get this issue.

Comment: is that the scroll bar for the simulator because it is too big to fit on your desktop,  did you try reducing the scale to make it fit

Comment: @CraigOtis What should the constraints be for the initial view controller?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Nope, that side bar is what the issue is. I'm not sure how to remove it. I dont think it's the simulator. I think it's the constraints.

Comment: You can ensure that you have all 4 constraints (top, bottom, left, right) for the view/view controller. Take a look in Xcode - do you notice any discrepancies between your left and right constraints? They should be nearly identical.

Comment: @CraigOtis The guide I'm watching has the right constraint as yellow circle saying: +4. However I just have a blue circle.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using autoLayout, this would appear to be an issue w/ not having a trailing constraint. http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

If not, I'd recommend looking into it as the pieces may be settling in the view w/out constraints and creating the bar to the right.